# Getting request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to send an Ajax request to a Tomcat server from my application, but I am getting this error (my web app is running on Chrome):

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I have tried using

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://localhost:8080/app',
```

but it didn't work.

My Ajax code:

```
 var arr = [1];
   $.ajax({ 
   url: 'http://localhost:8080/app',
   type: 'POST',
   contentType:'application/json',
   headers: {
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://localhost:8080',
   },
       data: JSON.stringify(arr[0]),
       success: function(data){
        //On ajax success do this
             alert(data);
          }
     });
```

Comment: that header must be set on the server, not the client.

Comment: on server where should i keep it

Comment: since you're not really using the response, you could use a plain old <form> tag to send the data instead of ajax, which should work without modifying the server,

Comment: no in this code i am not using i need to use in future

Comment: what happens if the REST endpoint is something i cannot control

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Basically, to make a cross domain AJAX requests, the requested server should allow the cross origin sharing of resources (CORS). You can read more about that from here: 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

In your scenario, you are setting the headers in the client which in fact needs to be set into http://localhost:8080/app server side code.

If you are using PHP Apache server, then you will need to add following in your `.htaccess` file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41854438/how-to-use-api-key-along-with-cors-in-web-api I am trying to use CORS along with an extra security but it's not working. Any idea?

Comment: The OP said he's using Tomcat

Comment: I have same issue bu that apis can return success when i cuse crul but in ajax shows this error?

Comment: I have same issue bu that apis can return success when i cuse crul but in ajax shows this error?

Comment: Doesn't this allow all origins?  Shouldn't that really be limited to the expected origins?

Answer (score 10):

**In case of Request to a REST Service:**

You need to allow the CORS (cross origin sharing of resources) on the endpoint of your REST Service with Spring annotation:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
```

Very good tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/