# not working properly ajax rest call

Tags: jquery, ajax

This call is making 2 requests at the same time but while using postman only one is generated. If any1 can help will be greatly appreciated. it was though only sending one at first but now every time 2 requests are generated. Though wile placing alert in the comment is only showing once on the screen.

If there actual URL is needed I will again edit the question and place the real value.

```
$(function(){
$("#form").on("submit", function(e){
    this.disabled = true;
    var Subject = $("input[name=Subject]").val();
    var Detail = $("textarea[name=Detail]").val();
    var Name = $("input[name=Name]").val();
    var Email = $("input[name=Email]").val();
    var Request = $( "#myselect option:selected" ).val();
    var data = JSON.stringify({u_source:"sssss", u_subject:Subject,u_description:Detail,u_name:Name,u_email:Email,u_category:Request})
    var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "something",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
"accept": "application/json",
"content-type": "application/json",
"authorization": "Basic something",
"cache-control": "no-cache"
 },
 "processData": false,
 "data": data,
 "dataType": 'json'
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
 alert('Thank you, Your feedback has been recorded');
 $('.overlay').hide();
 form.reset();
});
$.ajax(settings).fail(function (response) {
 alert('Sorry, Something went wrong. Please try again');
 $('.overlay').hide();
 form.reset();
});
  e.preventDefault(); 
  });
});
```

sorry if I had made a silly mistake, please help me to sort that out

Comment: You cannot send `POST` data AND use `jsonp` as the dataType, because it appends some data to the querystring. Try it without using jsonp as the datatype. [See this post for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508198/how-to-use-type-post-in-jsonp-ajax-call)

Comment: Cross-domain security prevents you from accessing the site from localhost. Maybe [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820142/getting-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check-no-access-control-allow-orig) can help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are a couple of things happening here that you need to fix.

Firstly,

> You cannot send `POST` data AND use `jsonp` as the `dataType`, because it appends some data to the querystring, forcing the request to be sent as a `GET` request.

Either use `json` instead, or remove it altogether. Similarly with `cache:true`, it also will have the same effect. Either of these will cause the request to be sent as a `GET` request.

Try with this request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://nespreprod.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/u_incident_rest_inbound", //your api url is here
    //Host: "nespreprod.service-now.com",
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json",
    accepts: "application/json",
    beforeSend: function(client) {
        //Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password);
        client.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic c3ZjLnJlc3QudHVyYXM6TjM1cmVzVEFQMQ==");
    },
    //Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password),
    success: function(client, status, error) {
        alert('Email Send');
        //$('.overlay').hide();
    },
    error: function(client, status, error) {
        alert('Please Try again Later!');
        //$('.overlay').hide();;
    }
});
```

Secondly, for the data that you are sending, you need to remove the single quotes around the parameters in the JSON.stringify call, ie this line:

```
 data: JSON.stringify({"u_source":"tarus", 'u_subject':Subject,'u_detail':Detail,'u_name':Name,'u_email':Email,'u_request':Request}),
```

Should becomd:

```
 data: JSON.stringify({u_source:"tarus", u_subject:Subject,u_detail:Detail,u_name:Name,u_email:Email,u_request:Request}),
```

Comment: No. You should leave the quotes for all actual strings, the variables should not have quotes around them

Comment: See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/as5gpw46/), it produces a correct JSON string

Comment: Can you update your question with the `HTML` that you are using?

Comment: I have updated the Question. Can you help. Still couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

try with something like that :) it works !

```
string data='name:test & email:test@test';
     $.ajax({
        url: "restApi.php"
        method: "POST",
        data: data
        contentType: "application/json"



 }


 success: function(){
            alert('Email Send'); 

});
```

// Php Page

```
if((isset($_POST['name']))&&(isset($_POST['email'])))
{
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email']);
}
```

Comment: Might work but i need need to make that working any how.